# gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just done a re-install my mac because of the error of npm,
and today I've done a `git clone` my project, and when i run `npm install` it returns an error.

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Volumes/StorageX/GitHub/boxity-app/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bintangtobing/.npm/_logs/2021-06-08T06_56_47_174Z-debug.log
```

I don't know why this happens, but I beg your help, any one can help me to solve this?
Please...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ubuntu 18.04:
nvm install 12.3.0
npm ci
```